Python, groupby by ID for function
came across this function to find local highs and lows around each row, where n1/n2 are the lookback periods
def pivotid(df1, l, n1, n2): 
    if l-n1 < 0 or l+n2 >= len(df1):
        return 0

    pividlow=1
    pividhigh=1
    for i in range(l-n1, l+n2+1):
        if(df1.low[l]>df1.low[i]):
             pividlow=0
        if(df1.high[l]<df1.high[i]):
             pividhigh=0
    if pividlow and pividhigh: 
         return 3 
    elif pividlow:
        return 1 
    elif pividhigh:
        return 2 
    else:
        return 0 

applying this back on dataframe with
df['pivot'] = df.apply(lambda x: pivotid(df, x.name, 10, 10), axis=1)

This will work properly if I just have 1 currency pair




DATE
ID
PX_HIGH
PX_LOW




0
2019-01-29
EURUSD Curncy
1.1450
1.1411


1
2019-01-30
EURUSD Curncy
1.1502
1.1406


2
2019-01-31
EURUSD Curncy
1.1514
1.1436


3
2019-02-01
EURUSD Curncy
1.1488
1.1435


4
2019-02-04
EURUSD Curncy
1.1466
1.1425


5
2019-02-05
EURUSD Curncy
1.1441
1.1401


6
2019-02-06
EURUSD Curncy
1.1410
1.1361


7
2019-02-07
EURUSD Curncy
1.1368
1.1325


8
2019-02-08
EURUSD Curncy
1.1351
1.1321


9
2019-02-11
EURUSD Curncy
1.1330
1.1267



applying
d1['pivot'] = d1.apply(lambda x: pivotid(d1, x.name, 1, 1), axis=1)




DATE
ID
PX_HIGH
PX_LOW
Pivot




0
2019-01-29
EURUSD Curncy
1.1450
1.1411
0


1
2019-01-30
EURUSD Curncy
1.1502
1.1406
1


2
2019-01-31
EURUSD Curncy
1.1514
1.1436
2


3
2019-02-01
EURUSD Curncy
1.1488
1.1435
0


4
2019-02-04
EURUSD Curncy
1.1466
1.1425
0


5
2019-02-05
EURUSD Curncy
1.1441
1.1401
0


6
2019-02-06
EURUSD Curncy
1.1410
1.1361
0


7
2019-02-07
EURUSD Curncy
1.1368
1.1325
0


8
2019-02-08
EURUSD Curncy
1.1351
1.1321
0


9
2019-02-11
EURUSD Curncy
1.1330
1.1267
0



however, if my data set consists of different IDs along a common index but with same time period starting from 01 Jan 2019, for example




DATE
ID
PX_HIGH
PX_LOW




1358
2019-01-29
XAUUSD Curncy
1312.02
1302.01


1359
2019-01-30
XAUUSD Curncy
1323.43
1309.10


1360
2019-01-31
XAUUSD Curncy
1326.33
1317.51


1361
2019-02-01
XAUUSD Curncy
1323.56
1316.24


1362
2019-02-04
XAUUSD Curncy
1319.11
1308.73


1363
2019-02-05
XAUUSD Curncy
1316.95
1310.80


1364
2019-02-06
XAUUSD Curncy
1315.87
1305.83


1365
2019-02-07
XAUUSD Curncy
1312.00
1302.85


1366
2019-02-08
XAUUSD Curncy
1315.71
1307.83


1367
2019-02-11
XAUUSD Curncy
1314.95
1303.74



I attempt to use these groupbys:
grouped1 = data.groupby('ID')
grouped1 = grouped1.apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
df['pivot'] = grouped1.apply(lambda x: pivotid(grouped1, x.index[0], 1, 1))
df['pivot'] = grouped1.apply(lambda x: float(pivotid(x, x.index[0], 1, 1))) 

they either dont work or is pulling up nan values for the pivot column
I know I can use rolling(n1).max() or argrelextrema but I would appreciate some help
as above, please see above
